# Get inner html of an element from another web page?

Tags: jquery, html, innerhtml

How to get `innerHTML` of an element from another web page using JavaScript?

Example:

```
<script>
  $.get(url, function(response) {
     var $response = $(response); // Code not working from this line
     alert($response.find('.result').html()); // get innhtml of element by class name from response
  });
</script>
```

Comment: alert your response see what you are getting

Answer (score 1):

That depend if your response contain html than this will work

```
    <script>
      $.get(url, function(response) {
         $('yourelement_selector',response).html();
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: `<scrip>` needs to be `<script>`

Problem 2: You haven't finished your function call to `get`, add `);` to the end of your script

Aside from that, **given suitable input**, the script [works as desired](http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/inner/1.html).

However, the vagaries of how jQuery (and/or the underlying browser methods it calls) mean that if the elements you are trying to match are *children* of the body element in the document you are loading, then they will be *top-level* elements in the jQuery object so you won't find them with `find` (as they are not descendants). If you want to match elements like that, use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead.

Comment: @JAslu — That site is not giving JavaScript on my site permission to read content from it.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's `.load()` will do exactly that:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score -1):

You can use below example of post method to get data from other site and put that data into your site div/span etc. data container.

```
$.post("http://www.otherweburl.com",function (data) {
        document.getElementById("htmlContainerDivOrSpanETC").innerHTML=data;
});
```

Comment: The question is asking how to get *an element* from another page, not the HTML of the entire page. It says nothing about using post, and nothing about the site being external.